# Using local resource after clickonce deployment

Tags: winforms, clickonce, reportviewer

I have a folder created to hold reports in a server. How do I save the path in my application such that when i deploy on client the path will now be my reportpath.

I have tried this form \ServerName\FolderName\ReportName.rdlc but doesn't work.

Comment: The first \ should be a \\. Is that a typo in the question or is that what your code is looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see [Accessing Local and Remote Data in ClickOnce Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d8saf4wy.aspx):

1. Create *FolderName* in your solution, add your report there and mark it as "Data"
2. use ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.DataDirectory folder as a base folder